# CakePHP CSV Import with Preview

Tags: cakephp, csv, import, preview

There are many usefull CSV-Importer, but i didn't found one with a "Preview" of the Data to import. So start to make my own: but i stuck on HOW to organise all this in a nice cake-like way (just started programming)

**Functions**

This importer should be/have/can:

1. easy attached to every controller (and set a default model, so the tool can be called with /url/controller/**csv-importer**
2. after accessing this csv-importer via URL, you see a pre-defined view of this importer with an upload form for the CSV, next step let you
3. choose delimiter, charset, primaryKey to sync with (those options can be preconfigured on loading the importer, so those options (part 3) would be skipped)
4. show the PREVIEW of data from the uploaded CSV, which record would be inserted, which record would be changed
5. you can select the rows which should be imported and IMPORT, or ABORT and re-upload the csv

**Problem**

how should a organise this to offer this as a tool, which can easy be accessed by an user from everywhere (where i added this importer)

i don't need code :) it's all about how to organise this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Datasource repository contains a CSV Datasource https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.0/

Doing this in a component is wrong in the MVC pattern. Data processing is a model task for obvious reasons like re-usability in a shell. And models are easier to unit test.

I don't understand how you intend to use this in every controller. If you need to display the uploaded CSV as a table on every page then simply do a requestAction() simply fetch the CSV data using the datasource I've told you from the *model* where needed and set it to the view.

Comment: ok, i understand the part about MVC logic. because there are many tables, i wanted to offer this feature to every controller. definitiv wrong. at the end, i planed to offer an easy import feature for authorised useres. so they can see bevor importing, if records would be inserted or updated, see the differences. and to insert/remove the function or also copy to other project easily..  datasources 2.0, will take at look at this. thank you.

Comment: thanks for the info about datasource. but the main problem is still about the global availability of the "importer". it's not just the data of the csv. this importer should be interactive -> revised the question